# Upload file to server is going through normal request, while ajax is not working Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, file-upload

i am currently trying to upload a file with an ajax request on rails. My controller code is (main action):

```
    def changePage
        @welcome = WelcomeController.new

        respond_to do |format|
          format.html
          format.js
        end
    end
```

My application is single paged, and the pages are changed via ajax requests and everything is working (but i am doint it with link_to, while in this case i use form_for - i do not know if this can be the cause). So in the view (changePage.html.index) i am rendering a partial view (_main.html.slim) which has the following code:

```
= form_for(:uploaded_file, :remote => true, :url => {:action => 'changePage'}, :html => 
    {:multipart=>true}, :authenticity_token => true) do |f|
                    div class="browse"
                        span
                            | Choose file..

                        = f.file_field :uploaded_file

                        div id="file-status"
                            | You have not selected any files yet.

                        = f.submit :value => "Upload"
```

So when the Upload button is triggered i end up with a normal request to the server, and not an ajax request (i have changePage.js.erb file). So if someone has some idea about why this is happening it would be nice. {:

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For ajax upload you can use gem [remotipart](http://os.alfajango.com/remotipart/).

Comment: Nice, but i would like to keep it simple. {:

Comment: By the way - the information you gave link to was outdated, the current repo is https://github.com/jangosteve/remotipart {:

Answer (score 0):

I am using a javascript plugin [File-Uploader](https://github.com/Valums-File-Uploader/file-uploader) . It's simple and works well . I hope it would help you ^_^

Answer (score -1):

You cannot just upload file with an AJAX request, it's technically impossible. So, your options are:

1. Use normal upload with full page request to keep it simple.
2. Use ugly hacks e.g. hidden iframe to achieve AJAX-like upload.
3. Use third-party uploader (there are plenty of them).

I suggest either option #1 or #3, depending on your requirements. #1 if you just need a simple upload, #3 if you need advanced features e.g. multiple files upload, drag & drop upload, chunked upload (for large files) etc.